# Why is Python skipping code? Openpyxl, 2-D Dictionaries and Exceptions

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, openpyxl

So I'm trying to use Openpyxl to read numbers off an excel file and add them together by SKU. It kinda works, but Python seeems to be skipping some lines of code and I can't quite understand why.

Basically, I want to add the costs of all the parts that make up a specific SKU and report on the total SKU Cost for month N-1, current month, and N+1. But when I run my code, it gets part of the information and simply ignores the rest.

Code:

```
for row in range(2, tab.max_row):
    try:
        if (tab[regCol + str(row)].value != "NAN" or \
            tab[lobCol + str(row)].value != "Family"):

        #Initialize missing SKUs
        print("R{}:".format(row))
        if tab[skuCol + str(row)].value not in skuMatrix:
            print("Creating {}".format(tab[skuCol + str(row)].value))
            skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value] = {}
            skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[prevCost + str(1)].value] = float(0)
            skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[currCost + str(1)].value] = float(0)
            skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[nextCost + str(1)].value] = float(0)

        #Update SKU value
        skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[currCost + str(1)].value] += float(tab[currCost + str(row)].value)
        print("\t[Curr] Updated value to {}".format(skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[currCost + str(1)].value]))

        skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[nextCost + str(1)].value] += float(tab[nextCost + str(row)].value)
        print("\t[Next] Updated value to {}".format(skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[nextCost + str(1)].value]))

        skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[prevCost + str(1)].value] += float(tab[prevCost + str(row)].value)
        print("\t[Prev] Updated value to {}".format(skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[prevCost + str(1)].value]))

    except TypeError as te:
        if not tab[prevCost + str(row)].value or \
           not tab[currCost + str(row)].value or \
           not tab[nextCost + str(row)].value:
               pass
        else:
            print("Error adding {}".format(str(te)))
```

...and here's what actually happens when I run it:

```
    R233:
    Creating 123-ABXY
    [Curr] Updated value to 0.5983
    [Next] Updated value to 0.5983
    R234:
    [Curr] Updated value to 0.8193
    [Next] Updated value to 0.8193
    R235:
    [Curr] Updated value to 0.9753000000000001
    [Next] Updated value to 0.9753000000000001
    R236:
    [Curr] Updated value to 1.0365
    [Next] Updated value to 1.0365
    R237:
    [Curr] Updated value to 68.9565
    [Next] Updated value to 68.9565

    [Cost]
    SKU                  Prior     Current  Current +1
    123-ABXY             $0.00      $68.96      $68.96
```

I can't figure out why it ignores the last 2 statements. I can understand showing the $0.00 if there was no data (but there is)....and in any case, shouldn't the [Prev] print statement show up anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: `except TypeError as te: pass` You're silently ignoring an exception... that would be the first place I'd look: replace the `pass` with `print("exception!")` for example.

Comment: `except ...: pass` isn't a magic "make it work" incantation. It's the programming equivalent of covering your ears and yelling "la la la la I can't hear you" while people desperately try to tell you that the building is burning down.

Comment: Probably should've shown the whole Except block... Updated the post to reflect that. But shouldn't the print statement work regardless?

Comment: Not if an exception causes it to not get reached.

Comment: So I guess the real question is: _"How does a pass work?"_ Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html), I thought it did 'nothing'.... meaning: Line X throws exception -> action is pass --> return to code at Line X+1 --> process statement. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Zosimorro that's correct, but it consumes the line. I'd bet those lines are throwing exceptions and you're ignoring them, which is why they don't appear. Replacing `pass` with `print("Ut Oh")` or something will show you.

Comment: @Zosimorro: When control leaves an exception handler, it doesn't go back to the `try` block. People tried designing languages where control goes back to the `try` after an exception handler, and it turns out that's a horrible design.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. @TemporalWolf Thanks for the input. Now it all makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Silently ignoring exceptions is a [**bad idea**](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/):

Without running your code, I can guess the exception you're ignoring:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` or

`TypeError: <type> indices must be integers, not NoneType`

Because you're trying to index objects without checking if they are available:

```
skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[prevCost + str(1)].value] += float(tab[prevCost + str(row)].value)
        print("\t[Prev] Updated value to {}".format(skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value][tab[prevCost + str(1)].value]))
```

If `tab[skuCol + str(row)].value`, or `skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value]` is `None`, this will throw a `TypeError` and be silently ignored.

Or, it could be that `skuMatrix[tab[skuCol + str(row)].value]` is an integer, which will then give

`TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` when you try to index it.

Or a dozen other options for your nested `.value` and `array[index]` calls.

And because you're silently ignoring them, you don't know which it is.

So **don't** ignore TypeErrors. **Bad things** will happen.

The only time you should be ignoring exceptions is when you:

a) specify what exception you are ignoring (as you did)

b) your code works without handling that exception (it doesn't)

Therefore, you can't ignore this exception.